# Bootstrap Button Color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a customized bootstrap navigation button created.

When the user hovers over the button, the button color changes from green to blue and a submenu drops down.

The user can then click a sub menu item to navigate to the desired page.

When the user moves the mouse away from the primary button and onto the sub menu, the primary button color changes back to green.

We'd like the primary button to stay blue when the user moves their mouse to the sub menu.

Here's the code in use currently:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Login Button Mouseover</title>
    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
<style>
        .btn {
            border-radius: 0rem; 
        }

        .btn-secondary {
            background-color: #55aa39;
        }
    
        .btn-secondary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active, 
        .btn-secondary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active, 
        .show>.btn-secondary.dropdown-toggle {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #55aa39; /* GREEN */
            border-color: #4e555b;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    
        /* set the background color on hover, focus, active */
        .btn-secondary:hover, .btn-secondary:focus, .btn-secondary:active {
            background-color: #223f8e !important; 
        }
    
            .dropdown-item a {
            margin-left: 10px;
            margin-right: 10px;
            width: 90%;
            margin: auto;
        }
    
        .dropdown-menu{
        margin-top: 0;
        display: hide;  /* toggle between hide or block to hide or show for dev */
        min-width: 12rem;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu{
        display: block;
    }
    
            .dropdown-item.active, .dropdown-item:active {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #007bff;

        }
    
            .dropdown-item:focus, .dropdown-item:hover {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #55aa39;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #000000;
            border-width: 1px;
        }
    

    /* STYLE THE CARET - DOWN POINTING TRIANGLE */
        .dropdown-toggle::after {
            display: inline-block; /* Default */
            width: 0; /* Default */
            height: 0; /* Default */
            margin-left: .3em; /* Default */
            vertical-align: middle; /* Default */
            content: ""; /* Default */
            border-top: .5em solid; /* caret size */
            border-right: .5em solid transparent; /* caret size */
            border-left: .5em solid transparent; /* caret size */
        }
    
    .mycustom {
            margin-left: 5px; 
            margin-right: 7px; 
            width: 95%; 
            text-align: center;
            margin: auto;
            min-height: 35px;
        }
    
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropdown").hover(function(){
        var dropdownMenu = $(this).children(".dropdown-menu");
        if(dropdownMenu.is(":visible")){
            dropdownMenu.parent().toggleClass("open");
        }
    });
});     
</script>
    
</head>

<body>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    
    
    <div class="dropdown show" style="margin: auto; text-align: center; width: 100px;">
      <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Login
      </a>

          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item mycustom" href="#">User Access</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item mycustom" href="#">Business Access</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item mycustom" href="#">Employee</a>
          </div>
    </div>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Hi @Wordpress-Pros.com please mark answer accepted if it really solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add some more code of in your style element

```
.dropdown.open > a.dropdown-toggle 
{
            background-color: #223f8e;
}
```

I am posting a complete answer to your query. I have made some change that are absolutely not necessary but its good to code this way.

Important changes made by me

1. Removed class *open* instead used *show* only.
2. Change in script as show class should be removed if dropdown is not visible.
3. prevented on click event as it requires popper.js
4. some changes in css.

Here is full code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Login Button Mouseover</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>

        :root {
            --green: #55aa39;
            --blue: #223f8e;
        }

        #dropdownMenuLink {
            background-color: var(--green); /* GREEN */
            font-weight: bold;
            border-radius: 0rem;
        }

            #dropdownMenuLink:hover, .dropdown.show > #dropdownMenuLink {
                background-color: var(--blue) !important;
            }

            #dropdownMenuLink::after {
                vertical-align: middle;
                border-top: .5em solid;
                border-right: .5em solid transparent;
                border-left: .5em solid transparent;
            }

        .mycustom {
            margin-left: 5px;
            margin-right: 7px;
            width: 95%;
            text-align: center;
            margin: auto;
            min-height: 35px;
        }
        .dropdown-menu {
            margin-top: 0;
            min-width: 12rem;
        }
        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
            display: block;
        }

        .dropdown-item.active {
            background-color: #007bff;
        }

        .dropdown-item:focus, .dropdown-item:hover {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #55aa39;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #000;
            border-width: 1px;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".dropdown").hover(function () {
                var dropdownMenu = $(this).children(".dropdown-menu");
                if (dropdownMenu.is(":visible")) {
                    dropdownMenu.parent().addClass("show");
                }
                else {
                    dropdownMenu.parent().removeClass("show");
                }
            });

            $("#dropdownMenuLink").click(function (e) { e.stopPropagation(); })
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <div class="dropdown" style="margin: auto; text-align: center; width: 100px;">
        <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Login
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item mycustom" href="#">User Access</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item mycustom" href="#">Business Access</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item mycustom" href="#">Employee</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Sandeep.  This almost works!

RIght now, if I mouseover the main button the background goes blue and stays blue if I mouseover and dropdown item.  

If I then move my mouse away and then mouse over the main button again the main button background color reverts to green.

Any thoughts?

Comment: hi @Wordpress-Pros.com can you please share what do you exactly want?

Comment: Thank you Sandeep!  Exactly what I needed.  Very grateful for the assist.

Comment: Hi @Wordpress-Pros.com please mark my answer accepted and upvote it.

Comment: Hi Sandeep.  I'd be happy to mark you answer as accept and upvote it but I can't find how to do either of those!  I'm not seeing any options to accept or upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Sandeep!  You're answer worked.  You're awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my updated code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Login Button Mouseover</title>

    
    
<!-- BEGIN CUSTOM BUTTON CODE -->
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>

          .btn-secondary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active, 
          .btn-secondary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active, 
          .show>.btn-secondary.dropdown-toggle {
              background-color: #55aa39; /* GREEN */
              font-weight: bold;
              border-radius: 0rem; 
          }

/* set the main button background color on hover, focus, active */
          .btn-secondary:hover, .btn-secondary:focus, .btn-secondary:active {
              background-color: #223f8e !important; 
          }

          .dropdown-menu {
              margin-top: 0;
              display: hide;  /* toggle between hide or block to hide or show for dev */
              min-width: 12rem;
          }

          .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu{
              display: block;
          }

          .dropdown-item.active, .dropdown-item:active {
              background-color: #007bff;
          }

          .dropdown-item:focus, .dropdown-item:hover {
              color: #fff;
              background-color: #55aa39;
              border-style: solid;
              border-color: #000;
              border-width: 1px;
          }

/* keep the button blue when hovered and when mousing over drop menu */
          .dropdown.open > a.dropdown-toggle {
              background-color: #223f8e;
          }

/* STYLE THE CARET - DOWN POINTING TRIANGLE */
        .dropdown-toggle::after {
            vertical-align: middle; /* Default */
            border-top: .5em solid; /* caret size */
            border-right: .5em solid transparent; /* caret size */
            border-left: .5em solid transparent; /* caret size */
        }

        .mycustom {
              margin-left: 5px; 
              margin-right: 7px; 
              width: 95%;
              text-align: center;
              margin: auto;
              min-height: 35px;
        }

    </style>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".dropdown").hover(function(){
                var dropdownMenu = $(this).children(".dropdown-menu");
                if(dropdownMenu.is(":visible")){
                    dropdownMenu.parent().toggleClass("open");
                }
            });
        });     
    </script>
    
<!-- END CUSTOM BUTTON CODE -->
    
    
</head>

<body>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    

    <div class="dropdown show" style="margin: auto; text-align: center; width: 100px;">
      <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Login
      </a>

          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item mycustom" href="#">User Access</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item mycustom" href="#">Business Access</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item mycustom" href="#">Employee</a>
          </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

We want the main button background to change to blue upon mouse over of the main Login button.

We want the main Login button background to stay blue as the user mousesover any drop down menu item.

If the user mouses away from either the main Login button or the drop down menu, we want the main background color to revert to green.

If the user then initiates another mouse over of the main Login button, We want the main button background to change to blue and the main button background to stay blue as the user mousesover any drop down menu item.

The issue is when the user moves their mouse away, to a different part of the page, and then returns to the button, and mouses over it, the main button background color stays green and doesn't change.

Thanks for your help with this Sandeep!

Comment: please upvote and accept answer if it helps.